# Screen mirroring Android to Windows 10: How to enable keyboard/mouse as input devices?

Tags: windows-10, android, miracast

I'm using Android's Miracast system to project my Android screen to my Windows 10 computer. This is working fine (though I notice I have to reboot my computer sometimes to get it to show up as an available device to the phone).

However, once I connect, I get this mysterious/unhelpful message:

```
Touch Input is Turned off. To turn it on, go
Back to your PC, and select action center >
Connect > the check box
```

As I've searched around, it appears this message is causing others confusion too. I think there is a checkbox in the Action center > Connect menu when connecting to some other devices (like maybe another Windows 10 box?). But nothing shows up in the Connect area when this Android device is connected, so I can't figure out how to enable touch controls - there's no checkbox to click.

(Basically I want to use my mouse and keyboard on the computer to control the inputs on the Android phone.)

Comment: Have you done all the actions described in the last entry of [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/used-connect-feature-and-now-touch-screen-on/b6f053a4-a7e6-4e1d-acea-2ce236f4be30) ?

Comment: @harrymc - Thanks - yes I found that article and followed the instructions precisely. It makes no difference - the Connect area of the Action Center simply doesn't show the Android device *even when I'm actively casting the screen to the PC*. So there's no checkbox to check, to enable mouse/keyboard. Or at least I can't find the checkbox and that post you shared doesn't seem to enable it.

Answer (score 9):

Ensure that the system service of *Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel*
(or *Tablet PC keyboard*) is on. If that does not help, read on.

The famous checkbox that everyone talks about but can only rarely find is here:

[image]

A test done by a user named rajeshthampi in the post
["Project to this pc" not available on Win 10 despite correct hardware](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2019734-project-to-this-pc-not-available-on-win-10-despite-correct-hardware)
shows that the checkbox is present when projecting from Windows to Windows,
but not when projecting from Android to Windows.

The conclusion of the user was that this checkbox being available
is dependent on the sender (Android) and not on the receiver (Windows).

I suggest therefore to avoid the standard built-in casting in Android
and to use a third-party Android product.

One of the following free apps might do the job :

- [ApowerMirror - Mirror&Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apowersoft.mirror)
- [AirDroid: Remote access & File](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid)
- [AirMirror: Remote control devices](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airmirror)
- [AirMore: File Transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.airmore)

In listing these apps, I'm judging purely by their descriptions, not
having tested any of them.

Comment: Thanks - it's possible Android, or some editions, do not enable touch input via Miracast. As I was poking around on that line of thinking, I noticed this semi-duplicate post on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28408679/wireless-display-plus-touch-input - I've seen screenshots of the magic checkbox - importantly, not only is the checkbox not there, but android device itself doesn't show up. So something is definitely buggy, IMO, on the Windows side too.

Comment: I would guess rather that Microsoft has created a proprietary extension to the Miracast protocol which is not part of the standard implemented by Android. There are some more possible products not listed in my answer such as TeamViewer QuickSupport and Mobizen.

Comment: The control extension is not just Microsoft - it's also supported by my LG TV. When I project my Laptop to my TV, the magic remote can be used to control my PC, but it does appear that Android does not implement the extension. I did read that Google don't officially support Miracast anymore as they want to push everyone to Chromecast so I doubt Miracast will be improved.

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative to Miracast - Try [MyPhoneExplorer](https://www.fosshub.com/MyPhoneExplorer.html) by [FJ Soft](https://www.fjsoft.at/en/highlight.php).

In phones with Android 5 (Lollipop) and newer versions, you can enable "Extras" > "Control Phone / Screen-Mirroring". This can be done via Wi-Fi, Bluetooth or USB after installing the companion app on the phone.

The feature gives you options to adjust zoom, type, gestures, etc.

[image: Control Phone Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks @xypha - this doesn't solve the screen casting solution, but it's an interesting alternative which is to use my computer's keyboard/mouse with my phone as the "monitor." It would help address my main issue in some ways.. I can't call it a solution for this question, but it is a nice idea and it is an open source app, so not as cruddy as some of the screen cast apps in the Play market. (So I'm upvoting - thanks for posting.)

Answer (score 1):

You can control the android phone through Windows Connect even with a touch screen laptop. You should use a 3rd party app to control it, as I use Genymobile/scrcpy don't need to install any apps on phone and completely free with tons of configuration. Link: https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy

Edit: Thank @SachithMuhandiram, now I know the rule

Answer (score 0):

I've found a for-fee product called Vysor that solves the problem via USB cable. This provides excellent, stable bandwidth and resolution. It has a free, crippled version or a full featured version for $10/year. It doesn't meet all the requirements in the question but it's the highest quality option I've found yet.

Requires USB debugging mode to be turned on and it side loads an apk on the phone. It works via executable on windows, Mac and Linux.

Comment: How about TeamViewer Host? Free for non-commerical use.